# KGpg only creates DSA/ElGamal key pairs

Tags: rsa, gnupg

KGpg running in openSUSE Leap 42.3 (Plasma 5.8.7) does not generate RSA keys in any way nor allows to select the pair capabilities.

In the "Key Generation" window the "Algorithm" combo box is empty (so no algorithm can be selected at all) and the "Capabilities" section is fully grayed out. By selecting "OK" (i.e. the only remaining option...) a DSA (Certify, Sign, Authenticate) and ElGamal (Encrypting) key pair is created.

The issue only affects KGpg since the CLI and Kleopatra can create any combination of keys without problems.

What could be causing the issue and any idea about how to solve it?

[image: KGpg Key Pair creation dialog]

Comment: This seems more like a configuration issue. Check out the KGpg documentation and if that doesn't help you, try your luck at [unix.se]. I do not know if this is on topic there, but it certainly is off topic here.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Same exact issue here.